# PHP: Accessing dictionaries from a JSON string

Tags: php, json, server-side

I'm writing a simple PHP script that makes an API call that returns JSON. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to take that JSON string, convert it into a dictionary, and access nested dictionaries/data within it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$url = http://exampleURLThatReturnsJSONString.com
$rawData = file_get_contents($url);
```

I've read that you should use something like `$decodedData = json_decode($rawData)`
, but I'm not sure what to do next, especially if I want to access nested dictionaries with a key like `Schedule`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: we dont know what you need to do 'next' either

Comment: php doesn't have "dictionaries". it has arrays. once you run your json string through json_decode, you'll end up with an array or an object. At that point, you access the data like you would any OTHER php array/object.

Comment: `json_decode` will decode your raw data, as you've suggested. What happens after that depends on the structure of your data (which you haven't shown) and the application (which you haven't described). As Dagon says: "we dont know what you need to do 'next' either"

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Once I get the data, which is television schedule data, I want to access the dictionary key path LinearScheduleResult/Schedule/Airings. Then for each object in `Airings` I want to add that to another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the decoded data like this:

```
echo $decodedData['key'];
```

This wil echo the value of the item in the dictionary with key 'key'. Nested values can be accessed like this:

```
echo $decodedData['key1']['key2']['...'];
```

You can always use `var_dump` to show what's inside the result. Also, read the [documentation on json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried: `$data = json_decode($rawData);
echo $data['LinearScheduleResult']['Schedule']['Airings'];`, but I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. Any ideas?

Comment: Two ways to go: use json_decode($data, true) (the second param will convert all objects to arrays) or use $data->LinearScheduleResult->Schedule->Airings;

Answer (score 5):

`json_decode($json, $assoc = false)` converts the json string into an object by default, or into an array if you specify `$assoc = true`

If you have `$assoc = false` then you must access the values by `$decoded_data->key`. Whereas if you have `$assoc = true` then you can do `$decoded_data['key']`

Answer (score 0):

json_decode return array or object to which access is like to array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php